# Что за области оставил производитель и можно ли их удалить?

Tags: windows, ssd, ноутбук, hp

Купил новый ноутбук HP 15s-fq2128ur без ОС (точнее FreeDOS).
Программа установки Windows 10 находит 3 уже размеченные области на SSD, суммарно в 6 Гб. Что они содержат и можно ли их удалить? Всё же 6 Гб для и так небольшого SSD - это немало.
[image: Области]

Comment: Запросили бы вы техподдержку HP, раз вам так эти 2% диска нужны. А то снесёте и потом долго чудесам удивляться имеете шанс. Хотя техподдержка у них тоже далека от идеала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы самостоятельно устанавливаете винду - можно смело снести области, объединить всё в одну неразмеченную область и поставить туда Windows.

Скорее всего - это "ошметки" от установки операционной системы на ноут. Дело в том, что современная FreeDOS, которая работает на современном железе - это очень непростая штука, подробнее написано [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/company/dcmiran/blog/666258/) - кстати, там как раз разбирается случай с HP - ноутбуком.

Если коротко пересказать содержимое статьи - то "Похоже, HP на самом деле ставит на диск Linux, а затем запускает DOS в виртуальной машине"